# Homebrewing tips for multi-table campaigns?

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques, homebrew, multiple-gm

To be clear, I am not looking for homebrew. I am only looking for tips for running games, with the current requirements I have set.

Anyway, I am going to be running a campaign for some new players. When I sent out a post (on a discord server I have with my friends) I got a massive amount of feedback of players, both experienced dnd veterans and people who wanted to learn how to play, who wanted to partake in the adventure. We have decided to run 3 tables concurrently. Myself and two of my friends will serve as the DMs, each governing a specific table. We also have one or two players who said they could fill in for a DM in the event they cannot make it. We are going to run a book campaign to serve as an introduction for the new players. (either Lost Mines or Dragon Heist)

Here is where I'd appreciate some pointers. We plan on having the characters of all the players across all tables know each other, because all of the players know each other, and since the majority of them are newbies, we'd like to emphasize the social aspect of playing dnd. This also lets us swap around tables if players quit, and have big multi table encounters. My idea was, after the book campaign is over, to have each table run whatever the DM wants, but it would all be set in the same world, so things that one table do could affect other tables. Any tips or pointers on how I could make this enjoyable for myself and all of the other players?

Comment: One can write books about that topic. In fact, people *have* wrote books about that topic.

Comment: Just to be clear: is the idea that each table would independently run the published adventure as written--no actions of one group impacting the scenario for the others--but then the follow-on campaign would be shared-world style? Or are you looking to run the published adventure shared-world?